# Body Parameter Accepted in query

Tags: c#, .net

What should I do to avoid this issue in my site 
I am getting this may be becouse of values generated in hidden fields like __VIEWSTATE AND __EVENTVALIDATION 
How to avoid this?

Comment: Please add correct tag information and show the problematic code. This is probably because you are reading input parameters using Request["paramKey"] and not Request.Form["paramKey"], so any form parameters can also be sent in the query string and will have the priority

Comment: Please improve your question by reading and following [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)